# FAN Speed Control - HP EliteBook 8440p

Tags: kubuntu, fan, overheating, temperature, fancontrol

I've HP Laptop EliteBook 8440p and I am new to linux. I want to control my laptop's Fan speed, I was able to do so very easily in windows 7 by using the HWinfo software but in linux it is difficult. I tried installing lm-sensors, xsensors and fancontrol packages.

The "sudo sensors-detect" command only detect "coretemp" and add it to the /etc/modules. After running "sudo service kmod start'' it says "there are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed".
I tried a FIX by mdhalien which **did not help** me at all.
Fix from the post:

> This can be fixed by relaxing an acpi check in the kernel (hmm), see
> https://hydra.geht.net/tino/howto/linux/fixes/w83627hf/ amongst others
> for more details. The way I fixed this is to edit /etc/default/grub to
> add acpi_enforce_resources=lax to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT
> giving:
>
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_enforce_resources=lax"
> Then need to update the boot configuration:
>
> sudo update-grub and reboot.

I am stuck here, please help me to control fan speed (I want it to run the Fan at full speed at all times, no matter core temp is high or low). There is no option to control Fan in BIOS.

Comment: Are you asking how to edit `/etc/default/grub`? Or have you already made the change and you're still unable to control fan speed?

Comment: @matigo I've already edited it, but it didn't made any difference.

Comment: How are you controlling your fan speed? What commands/tools? What settings have you set? If you can [edit] your question with this information, it *may* be possible to offer a solution 

Comment: I am not controlling it. I am unable to control speed, as far as I know the controlling fan is the next step after pwmconfig shows the detected sensors. I would set the settings if pwmconfig would show some sensors.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, the HP Elitebook series don't have a tmp sensor output to the  OS. Some machines like this works automatically and independently, e.g. thermostat,